# html extension using database

Tags: php, html

Today I saw a blog and a web page (a huge one, very popular) with .html extension, but why? How is he (the page) make the query to db to retrieve data from it?

I know with HTML you can't query a database. With PHP you can. But it has .html extension.

I already made web pages, using php and mysql to store and retrieve data (in the most case with $_GET['url'] than query the database -identifer-). I know that every page request, page visit it makes the mysql server to start working (e.g query), and if the page is very popular to not overkill the server (machine) the data is already stored in .html? Or how is it working? I also saw this on a blog (wordpress).

Sorry for my english. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's up to the server to figure out what to do with the extension of the page - and it's configurable. For instance, in Apache, you can use `AddHandler` to specify that .php files are handled by PHP, but you can also specify that .html files are handled by PHP. You can make the server do whatever you want, but by convention, the .html page will return a HTML page (makes sense). To the protocol, which is what the server is actually "talking", the extension of the page doesn't matter one bit. What's more important is to be true to the `content-type` and `accept` HTTP header and the doctype of the page, which is how clients and servers *really* figure out what's being sent.

Answer (score 2):

Usually this is done using Mod Rewrite within the .htaccess file.

It's not actually a static HTML page, it's just that the URL get's read in one way (The htaccess file reads the URL, but loads a different web page (IE PHP etc)) and send's the details of the URL as a variable to that dynamic page.

Here's more information: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

It can also be done using .htaccess' AddType option, which can tell the server make make any extion (such as .html) work as a PHP file for example.